# React-soundloud-embed error

Tags: reactjs, soundcloud

I'm trying to embed a soundcloud track. I've imported the ReactSoundcloud to the page and now I'm getting these errors after using it inside the return. What am I doing wrong? (p.s. the url value is there as a placeholder for testing purposes)

[image]

My code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import ReactSoundcloud from 'react-soundcloud-embed';
import ArtistList from '../../data/artistlist.jsx';



let artistlist2017 = ArtistList.data;
// Artist Section

class Artists extends React.Component{
  render(){

    var artistPrint = artistlist2017.map(function(artist, index){
      return (
        <div className="each_artist" key={index}>
          <img
            src={artist.src} alt=""
          />
          <h1>{artist.name}</h1>
          <h3>{artist.description}</h3>
          <ReactSoundcloud url={"https://soundcloud.com/icebound/dusty-breaks-at-the-bottom-of-the-random-crates"}/>
        </div>
      );
    });
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="artist_block">
          <div>
            <div className="rotate_left_header">
              <h2>
                2017 Featured Artists
              </h2>
            </div>

            <div className="artists">{artistPrint}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
};

export default Artists;
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed my soundcloud component to

```
class ReactSoundcloud extends React.Component 
{

    constructor()
    {
        super();
        this.props = 
        { 
            width: "100%",
            height: "450px",
            url: "https://soundcloud.com/icebound/dusty-breaks-at-the-bottom-of-the-random-crates",
            autoPlay: false,
            hideRelated: false,
            showComments: true,
            showUser: true,
            showReposts: false,
            visual: true,
            color: "ff5500"
        };
    }

    render() {
        const { url, width, height, autoPlay, hideRelated, 
                showComments, showUser, showReposts, visual, color } = this.props;

        var src = visual ? 
                    `https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=${url}&amp;auto_play=${autoPlay}&amp;hide_related=${hideRelated}&amp;show_comments=${showComments}&amp;show_user=${showUser}&amp;show_reposts=${showReposts}&amp;visual=${visual}` :
                    `https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=${url}&amp;color=${color}&amp;auto_play=${autoPlay}&amp;hide_related=${hideRelated}&amp;show_comments=${showComments}&amp;show_user=${showUser}&amp;show_reposts=${showReposts}`;

        return (
            <iframe 
            width={ width } 
            height={ visual ? height : "auto" } 
            scrolling="no" 
            frameBorder="no" 
            src={ src } />
        );
    };
}
module.exports = ReactSoundcloud;
```

https://github.com/keske/react-soundcloud/blob/master/src/ReactSoundcloud.js

if ya look in source there is bit off diff

first usage of static defaultProps = {  give me browsefy error,
second frameBorder="no"in source  frameborder="no"

my not tested enought well but music now plays on my page !! :)

hmm i dont know why warning appears

'Warning: ReactSoundcloud(...): When calling super() in `ReactSoundcloud`, make sure to pass up the same props that your component's constructor was passed.'